# Starting with Python

Tags: python

Just wondering what the best way to get started learning Python to do backend engineering is and what the best framework to learn for it is (Pyramid, DJango etc...).  I have done algorithms in school, build iOS apps and know Java, Scala, OCaml (lol), Racket (lol) and Objective C.  I currently have to use Parse for my apps but want to build backend engineering skills.  I'm thinking I might as well do the code academy course but the ones I've done from them don't seem in depth enough.  Maybe an Udemy course?  I want to get good enough to get an internship in backend engineering next summer.  Need to find the best resources to do that before then.  Thanks!!

Comment: Unfortunately, questions looking for off-site resources explicitly off-topic on StackOverflow.  But, If you know all those other languages, learning Python should be a walk in the park.  Might I recommend taking a look at the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)?  Beyond that, there is no real "best" framework ... Just pick one and learn it.  Learning more is just a matter of sitting down with it for a while and connecting the dots.

Answer (score 2):

While that question is quite open-ended, I personally think using Pyramid right out of the gates was super helpful. One of the pillars of this project is documentation, and their ideology is that you pay for what you use, giving developers the ability to customize their web applications to a good extent. Check out the docs here http://docs.pylonsproject.org/en/latest/docs/pyramid.html!

They also have excellent tutorials that guide you through the traditional "Hello, world!" application, and also more advanced stuff, like how to work with sqlalchemy to utilize databases in your web applications. This is how I learned essentially all of what I know about the framework! I would definitely recommend this, especially if you are just looking to start out and get your feet wet. But, as I said, this is my own opinion, and am sure that there are others with differing opinions on the matter. Best of luck!

Comment: Please don't answer questions like these. Now the OP is stuck with this question, as they no longer can delete it themselves.